# function in matlab- undefined input argument error

Tags: matlab

I can't understand what the problem is with this code. If anyone can help I will be thankful.

```
function [out] = detj(in1)
%DETJ Summary of this function goes here
%Detailed explanation goes here: N is 2*50 matrix and in1 is scaler
    global N 
    out=(1/8)*(N(1,in1));
end
```

The error is :

> Input argument "in1" is undefined.
>  
>   Error in ==> detj at 7
>   out=(1/8)*(N(1,in1));

I defined N in another file

```
N=importdata('Nodes.txt'); %Matrix of nodes
```

Comment: If you wish to get answer, I would advise to split up the statement where your error is occurring as well as give an example of inputs. I.e, what do in1, in2, in3, in4, N, r, s, look like? How are you calling this function?

Comment: It seems you are calling `detj` without any input argument

Comment: As Durkee suggested, add the part of your main script where you call the function `detj` and where you create `N` and `in1` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No thing wrong with your code, you just used the function the wrong way.

To use a Function in Matlab you need to call it, NOT to run it directly.

This is your original function code

```
function [out] = detj(in1,in2,in3,in4)
      %DETJ Summary of this function goes here
      %   Detailed explanation goes here %N is 2*50 Matrix
     global N r s
    out=zeros(2,2);
    for m=1:2
    for n=1:2
     out(m,n)=(1/8)*(((N(1,in1)-N(1,in3))*(N(2,in2)-N(2,in4))-(N(2,in1)-N(2,in3))*(N(1,in2)-N(1,in4)))-r(1,m)*((N(1,in3)-N(1,in4))*(N(2,in1)-N(2,in2))-(N(2,in3)-N(2,in4))*(N(1,in1)-N(1,in2)))+s(1,n)*((N(1,in2)-N(1,in3))*(N(2,in1)-N(2,in4))-(N(2,in2)-N(2,in3))*(N(1,in1)-N(1,in4))));
 end
 end
end
```

To use your function I tried a simple code,

```
clc;clear;
global N
global r
global s 
N=ones(2,50);
r=ones(2,2);
s=ones(2,2);
detj(1,2,3,4)
```

And I got answer as

```
ans =

 0     0
 0     0
```

So no thing wrong with your function, just you need to know how to use it.

Let me know if my answer is not clear else good luck.

Comment: my bad, so if we run a function it doesn't matter that we get an error?

Comment: Yes exactly, actually I don't see any reason to run a function. Just make sure you save your function every time you make change to it